# How do you make a nav bar "sticky"?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm making a site for a friend and I would like to make the nav bar sticky. Here's an example: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp. I would like to have a picture where the header is in the example.

Here is the code I have already made:

```
<html>
<head class="masthead">

    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylehom.css">
    <link href="https://dub110.afx.ms/att/GetInline.aspx?messageid=1f91e2e4-f236-11e4-9965-002264c20aa4&attindex=0&cp=-1&attdepth=0&imgsrc=cid%3apart1.04010900.00040603%40btinternet.com&cid=07bd617fb040a20e&hm__login=edwinshepherd1&hm__domain=live.co.uk&ip=10.211.20.8&d=d97&mf=0&hm__ts=Mon%2c%2004%20May%202015%2016%3a39%3a02%20GMT&st=edwinshepherd1%25live.co.uk%407&hm__ha=01_9ec1f64927212e04419eae777113f0da6f91696bf6888f10c6ec81157beef631&oneredir=1" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style>



.jumbotron {
   background-image:url('//c1.staticflickr.com/9/8723/16322346204_6a1a86440a_c.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:125px;
  left:25px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}


.learn-more {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.neighborhood-guides {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid#dbdbdb
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
function resizeIframe(iframeID) 
{       
    var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(iframeID);
    var container = document.getElementById('content');
    iframe.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';            
} 

.blog ,iframe { overflow:hidden; }
    </style>

  <style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style>


    <title>The Unthinkable</title>
</head>

  <body>
    <!---<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="nav">
       <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/9/8612/16254026843_667c68f054_n.jpg" alt="LOGO" style="width:120px;height:30px;border:0"></a></li>
          <li><a href="browse.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
           <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <li><a href="http://theunthinkable.tk/alpha/music.html">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>    
</nav>---!>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>My name is Joe. I make music.</h1>
        <p>This is where it begins.</p>
        <a href="#blog">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="nav">
       <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/9/8612/16254026843_667c68f054_n.jpg" alt="LOGO" style="width:120px;height:30px;border:0"></a></li>
          <li><a href="browse.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
           <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <li><a href="http://theunthinkable.tk/alpha/music.html">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>    
</nav>

    <div class="neighborhood-guides">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>What is this?</h2>
            <p>This website is home to the music project: The Unthinkable.</p>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="225" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/77100370&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="225" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188923984&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">


            <div class="thumbnail">
                <iframe width="100%" height="225" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/187159699&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
            </div>
                </div>
</div>
 </div>
<a name="blog"></a>     
<div class="blog">

<iframe src="http://theunthinkable-blog.tk/wordpress/" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="300%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>         

</div>

    <div class="learn-more">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Edwin's Webspace</h3>
            <p>Ever wanted your own place on the web; but don't know how?</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about Edwin's Webspace</a></p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Dot TK</h3>
            <p>The company who gave us this domain name.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.freenom.com/en/index.html">Learn about Dot Tk</a></p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Hostinger</h3>
            <p>The company who hosts this site 24/7!</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.hostinger.co.uk/">Learn more about Hostinger</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




</div>

<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5573204519348e87" async="async"></script>

<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5573204519348e87" async="async"></script>
</body>
```

This can be viewed at http://www.theunthinkable.tk:

I would prefer if the solution was html or css as I have never used jquery before. However If that is the only way please give me all the instructions for the set-up of it.

Thanks to anybody who helps :D

Also is it possible to get rid of the white boarders around the nav bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS only to stick it to the top
    header {
        width: 100%
        height: */whatever you want*/
        position: fixed
        top: 0
    }

If you want to create that cool effect where the nav covers the title on scroll you would need to use javascript. I'll comment it for you to make it easier to use

```
//.onscroll() is a built in method from your browser (window)
//it fires ...wait for it.... onscroll
window.onscroll = function () {
    // adjust the 0 to trigger the effect at the right point
    if (!docked && (menu.offsetTop - scrollTop() < 0)) {
      menu.style.top = 0;
      menu.style.position = 'fixed';
      menu.className = 'docked';
      docked = true;
    } else if (docked && scrollTop() <= init) {
      menu.style.position = 'absolute';
      menu.style.top = init + 'px';
      menu.className = menu.className.replace('docked', '');
      docked = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: This article provides another great way to do it. https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2